# Zxing how to save the image or make QRCode?

Tags: java, android-studio, zxing, qr-code

I integrated Zxing in Android studio and scanning, to save scanned images.

But 'Zxing' is not returning any image, so I need to convert the result into a  QRCode.

Is there any other way to save QRCode images?

---

I tried teaching Bhavika provided

However, the following error

import java.awt.Color; can not resolve symbol 'Color'

import java.awt.Graphics2D; can not resolve symbol 'Graphics2D'

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; can not resolve symbol 'BufferedImage'

import javax.imageio.ImageIO; can not resolve symbol 'ImageIO'

I do not know how he happened, what is the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, isn't ZXing for recognition only?

Comment: You mean not retrieve image?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've only used ZXing once. I've captured the image and saved it in a `Bitmap`. Then i used ZXing to detect 2D-Barcodes (QR-Codes) in this image. It would help, if you could show us some of your code.

Comment: Thank you: D But I have found other ways to achieve QRCODE production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code to make QRCODE image

---

```
            QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(SendQrCode, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);//SendQrCode is Want to make a string
            int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
            int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_result_qr)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

See if [this link](http://www.journaldev.com/470/generate-qr-code-image-from-java-program) helps you. The tutorial is also converting an image to QR code.

Comment: import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
cannot resolve symbol why?